# Qt Sockets, force dicconect when left in FIN-WAIT-1 state

Tags: qt, sockets

I have a Qt project running on windows acting as a server. (5.9 on 32b MSVC2015, we also build for Ubuntu but have yet to see this issue)   Many hundreds of TCP/IP sockets come and go to machine with normal well-behaved sockets.  The connection software used by the remote parties is out of our control. While most of it is well formed, some of it is not.  We have one user agent who manages to connect and then disconnect improperly, leaving the socket dangling open in the FIN-WAIT-1 state.  In fact they can leave hundreds of sockets open that way as they retry.

On the Qt side we have dropped the connection with a call to abort() on the socket before deleting it. [close() was also tried, no difference] But the inbound connection remains in the FIN-WAIT-1 state forever, not a robust long term answer.

Is there way from within the Qt app to clear these off?  I do not see any lower level calls that might help with this.  [Aside, we just use the popular tool 'cports.exe' to clear them off by hand for now.]

Comment: How did you use `close()` ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Just a simple call to QTcpSocket socket close()  the socket ptr lives in another class and key code is below.     

\ if (socket != NULL) {
\        // Changed to abort() after seeing many hanging "Fin Wait 1" states
\        // from what seems to be an attack of sequential ports from a bad Client
\        // but it looks like bad disconnects can still hang sockets
\        socket->abort();  // was: close();
\        delete socket;
\        socket = NULL;
\    }
\

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, cannot seem to get cntl-K to work

Comment: Yes, my question was are you deleting the socket after `close()` ? check [This](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-61677.html)

Comment: Also try to check your system for default settings (keep a live)